# Usage et origine de « c'est du toc »

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, langage-informel

> Ton ordinateur c'est du toc. Tiens, J'ai un bon logiciel antivirus.

La tournure **c'est du toc** signifie-t-elle ici que l'ordinateur ne fonctionne pas bien ?

D'où vient cette tournure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C'est pour dire que c'est de la mauvaise qualité, de la camelote

Cf [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toc) :

> Imitation, objet factice ou notion sans valeur : « ce bijou, c'est du
>   toc », « une montre en toc », « une idée en toc ».